# igraph in R: delete edges based on node attributes

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, subgraph

I have an `igraph` object called `y` that contains `inventor` as vertices and `patent` as edges.

Each `vertex` has an attribute `city`, referring to the location of the inventor.
Each `edge` has an attribute `h_city`, referring to either the location of the inventor **or** the firm.

I want to select only the patents on which at least one of the inventors is located in city X and that at least one inventor on that patent is NOT in city X.

If I run the following script, I also end up with patents in which **none** of the inventors lives in city X, but the firm is located there:

```
city_x<-subgraph.edges(y, which(E(y)$h_city=="x"))
```

If I run the following script, as suggested by MrFlick to answer a different question, I end up also with patents in which all inventors are from city X:

```
city_x<- subgraph.edges(y, E(y)[inc(V(y)[city=="x"])])
```

Below I give an example, also produced by MrFlick for a different answer - I slightly changed it:

```
library(igraph)

y <- graph.atlas(711)
V(y)$name <- 1:7
V(y)$prop <- c(1,2,2,3,3,1,1)
V(y)$color <- ifelse(V(y)$prop>=3, "red","yellow")
```

This produces:

```
E(y)[inc(V(y)[prop>=3])]
#Edge sequence:

#[3]  4 -- 3
#[4]  5 -- 4
#[5]  6 -- 5
#[10] 5 -- 3
```

With this code I also include edge #4 between node number 4 and 5 because they both have `prop>=3`. I do not want to select that edge. At least one node need to match the criteria and at least one node does not.

For this example: How do I select only the edges on which at least one of the nodes has `prop>=3` but at least one node incident on the edge does not.

**EDIT**:

I have also tried (incorrectly, I bet) to use functions as `neighbors` and `incident`, but none seem to work:

```
test2<-graph.neighborhood(subgraph.edges(g,which(E(y)$h_city=="x")),order = 1)
test3<-neighbors(g, which(E(y)$h_city=="x"))
test4<-incident(g, which(E(y)$h_city=="x"))
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not try something like `induced.subgraph(y, which(V(y)$city=="x") )`?

Comment: Thanks Vincent! But if I run that script I do not include the patents on which one of the inventors is not from city X. And I do want these in my selection.

Comment: With `neighbors` rather than `induced.subgraph` then?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work - or I wrote it up wrong.

Comment: Can you edit you question to describe what you tried with `neighbors`?

Comment: Yes, I did the edit above. Thanks!

Comment: OK! last request: can you add a reproducible example. E.g. based on a famous graph (`graph.famous`).